# How to zip a folder using AutoIt

Tags: zip, autoit

I have code to create zip a folder below code is working for zipping a file

```
$ZipArchive = @ScriptDir & "\test.zip"; Put here the full path and name ame of archive you would like to create
$AddFile = @ScriptDir & "\zip.au3"; Put here the the File you would like to compress in the zip   
$AddFile2 = "c:\config.sys"; Take another File ...
```

$oShell = ObjCreate("Shell.Application"); Create s shell Object

```
if IsObj($oShell) then                          
    InitZip($ZipArchive); Create an emtpy zip file with header      
    $oDir = $oShell.NameSpace($ZipArchive); Use the zip file as an "Folder"
    $oDir.CopyHere ($AddFile); Copy a file in the "Zip Folder" 
    $oDir.CopyHere ($AddFile2); Copy a second file
    sleep (500); Give the Objekt a litte bit time to work 
else 
    Msgbox (0,"Error","Error creating Object.")
endif 

Func InitZip ($zip_path_name)
    $init_zipString= Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6);Create the Header String 
        for $n =1 to 18;the     
            $init_zipString= $init_zipString & Chr(0);Header    
        next 
    $file =FileOpen($zip_path_name,2)                       
    FileWrite($file,$init_zipString);Write the string in a file 
    FileClose($file)
EndFunc
```

Comment: what is your question or problem please tell.

Comment: My problem is i am not able to zip a folder using autoit

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use e.g. **7z via the Run** command.

A command to compress one folder into an archive looks like this:

```
7z a -r archive.7z directory
```

In **AutoIt** this would be

```
local $command = "7z a -r archive.7z directory"
Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & $command, @ScriptDir)
```

You might need to specify also the path to the 7z executable if the 7z directory is not included in your global path variable.

Comment: Note that this requires you to put all the files into one directory beforehand. After you have all files in one directory this is already a working example.